# why do i get the error "Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed: invalid token"?

Tags: android, build.gradle

[Here's the link to build.gradle . I'm not able to find the error.](https://github.com/kabburesai/Demo.git)

Comment: please be more specific on your error. You can post the stacktrace here so we can help you easily. You can also provide some details on when or how did the error occured.

Comment: @TentenPonce I'm new to android and don't know the cause for the error. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project it gives this message in the Event log ::                                           Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
    build file 'G:\Whatsapp\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ^
    1 error
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 m 17 s 675 ms)

Answer (score 1):

I fix your code and build it a success. You can see the PR in Github.
I think it just a little environment setting problem.

https://github.com/kabburesai/Demo/pulls

Update:
I build it again and find the styles.xml has incorrect, so I fix it also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib1fp.png)

Comment: I appreciate your help. but  i downloaded that project and tried to run but it say's "Load Settings
     Cannot load settings from file 'G:\Whatsapp\Whatsapp.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[23,37]
     Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
     Please correct the file content"

Comment: Hi, I build it again and find the styles.xml has incorrect, so I fix it also.

Comment: Could you tell what changes do i have to make in my project. when I tried to run new project. Event log prints this::                                                                                       
 * What went wrong:
This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 4.1 or newer.

Comment: Oh ... I think your android studio version is standard. so I downgrade for you, you can try again.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token mostly means syntax error only. There's just a command(code, character or words) that was incorrectly placed.

According to your error, it points to your `build.gradle (root)`.

Comment: But i haven't made any changes in that file. Did you run the project?